# Doctrine + Mongo : How to define an id which maps to an embedded document in mongo?

Tags: mongodb, doctrine

The output of a Mongo Map/reduce is stored in the db as:

> {
>          { _id: { "groupby1": "field1", "groupby2": "Field2"}, 
>              value: { "valuefield1": "value1", "valuefield2": "value2"}
>          }
>      }

In a doctrine document, how can we define the `id` field to map to an embedded document?

If I define it as a collection or `EmbedOne`,

`/**
     * @MongoDB\EmbedOne ,(target="Articles\Id", strategy='none')

     */`

Doctrine genereates an exception saying that the document does not have an id or primary key "Every Document must have an identifier/primary key"

If I define it as an `id`, then the failure is at the Mongo cursor, which is trying to load an array to a scalar field.

Any pointers on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are setting a custom id in the _id field, its easiest to use the default and store the groupby fields as keys in the document:

```
{
    _id: ObjectId("xxx")
    "groupby": [
        "field1",
        "field2"
    ],
    "value": [
        "value1",
        "value2"
    ]
}
```

Comment: The emit is something like this. 

`    emit( { groupby1: this.groupby1, groupby2: this.groupby2},
    { valuefield1: this.valuefield1, valuefield2: this.valuefield2 } );`

If I change the id to something else, not sure if the map reduce will work correctly. Any pointers?

Comment: Oh, i see it now, it's because there is no _id in the outer document. You might have to ask the doctrine folks how to do that but it seems like in the emit function you should include some sort of id. Not sure you can have the mep reduce output be an embedded document in that case.